# How to select the 3th, 4th, 7th, 8th, and 11th li?

Tags: html, css, sass

On small screen sizes I need to able to select every 3rd item. I am using `:nth-child(3n)` to accomplish this. Then at desktop sizes I need to be able to overwrite that and select the 3rd, 4th, 7th, 8th, and 11th(last) item. How can I do that?

Thank you!!

Comment: Use media queries

Comment: `:nth-child(3),:nth-child(4),` etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to select items in groups of two starting at third, two selected and two not selected. You can do with only two selectors:

```
:nth-child(4n + 3) // select 3rd, 7th and 11th
:nth-child(4n + 4) // select 4th and 8th
```

Use *media queries* to limit to the desired sizes:

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    li:nth-child(3n) {
        background: green;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    li:nth-child(4n + 3),
    li:nth-child(4n + 4) {
        background: red;
    }
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>element 01</li>
    <li>element 02</li>
    <li>element 03</li>
    <li>element 04</li>
    <li>element 05</li>
    <li>element 06</li>
    <li>element 07</li>
    <li>element 08</li>
    <li>element 09</li>
    <li>element 10</li>
    <li>element 11</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer that's what I was looking for! I still had to add one more selector to fully overwrite the mobile style, so I had to add `li:nth-child(3n)` with the new style rule in my media query *above* the other two selectors you gave. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need two media queries - one for small screens and one for large screens.

You should also use a mixin for more maintainable code.

```
@mixin liStyles{
  color: red;
  font-size 24px;
}

/* phones */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
  li:nth-child(3n){
    @include liStyles;
  }
}

/* desktop */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
  li:nth-child(3), li:nth-child(4), li:nth-child(7), li:nth-child(8), li:nth-child(11){
    @include liStyles;
  }
}
```